# New install Wordpress 3.9 is throwing error: "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2014/09" when uploading an image

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, centos

I did a new install of Wordpress on CentOS 6.5 and when I try to upload an image, I get an error stating:

```
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2014/09
```

I checked the permissions and groups and I believe everything looks correct.

```
//User "apache" is member of group:
apache : apache webadmins

//Permissions on wp-content:
drwxr-sr-x.    4 root    webadmins  4096 Aug 29 10:07 wp-content
```

I've read it should be 755, which it is, but this doesn't allow Wordpress to create any directories in there. What should it be so that it (and any plugins) can create upload directories (yet is secure)?

Should it be 775?

*I checked two other Wordpress servers and one has 770 and the other has 775. Which is correct?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing it to 775 should work and be fine. The group webadmins needs write permissions.

Comment: do you know why the zip file from WordPress had it set to 755?

Comment: Don't know, but probably because Wordpress is assuming the file will be owned by your webserver user (apache) and not root.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks! do you know, should it be owned by apache instead of root? is one a more secure setup?

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience with this but having it owned by apache might be better. Sometimes I've seen this cause issues though when new files get created. Sorry I can't give you a more definitive answer on that.